# net::ERR_ABORTED) How can I solve js file path issue in the Template's plugins (Converting Bootstrapt to WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm converting Bootstrap Template to WordPress.

I cannot load dynamic slide, I guess there is a trouble to access js file.

Error Message from Chrome console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLnmb.png)

in my functions.php

```
function theme_js() {
wp_enqueue_script('script_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

However, in the scripts.js file there is a code to return a specific path.

```
var PLUGINS_LOCALPATH = '/plugins/';
-------------(more)-----------------
    getScriptLocation: function() {
  var location = $('body').data('plugins-localpath') || null;
  if (location) {
    return location;
  }
  return PLUGINS_LOCALPATH;
},
```

so this will try to reach such as "http://localhost/wordpress.test/plugins/slider-revolution/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?v=5.4.4" this kinda path, but I think wordpress need to use php based path like

I am wondering how can I solve this issue.

could you give me some solutions? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i actually had a simmilar problem today and my solution was really simple.
 I updated my word press and all was fixed.